# Find selected features by RandomizedLogisticRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I'm doing binary classification on 300Ksamples and 19 features.
I employed RandomizedLogisticRegression() in scikit for feature selection.
I'd like to know how can I find which features are selected by RandomizedLogisticRegression().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`get_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression.get_support) function:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import RandomizedLogisticRegression

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

clf = RandomizedLogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
print clf.get_support()

#prints [False  True  True  True]
```

Alternatively, you can get the indices of the support features:

```
print clf.get_support(indices=True)
#prints [1 2 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. It was quite helpful.